# WordPress adding stylesheet to plugin menu page

Tags: php, css, wordpress

**Solved**

I needed to call `new Form()`, I though I did in WebSecurity.php

```
array(__CLASS__,'ws_page_render') //I though this would call new Form()
```

---

I'm trying to add a stylesheet to my menu page in a WordPress plugin. I read the documentation and applied it but it still doesn't show in the header. All resources are added. I hope that somebody can help me.

I need to add `style.css` in the header so that `request_form.php` can render the css on the webpage.

I have added the stylesheet with the correct method:

**I have updated the Form class**

```
    function __construct()
    {   
        //browser finds the style sheet
        // output: http://cms.local/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/web_security_extension/includes/resources/css/ws-style.css
        echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'resources/css/ws-style.css';

        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'ws_load_css_1') );

        include_once WSS_EXTESION_DIR . '/includes/views/request_form.php';
    }

    function ws_load_css_1() 
    {
          wp_register_style( 'ws_css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'resources/css/ws-style.css');
          wp_enqueue_style( 'ws_css' );
    }
```

**Project structure**

**Root plugin**

- includes

  - resources

    - css

      - ws-style.css
  - views

    - request_form.php
  - From.php
- init.php
- WebSecurity.php

init.php

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: websecurityscan
Description:
Version: 0.1
Author: 
*/

define('WSS_EXTESION', __FILE__);

define('WSS_EXTESION_DIR', untrailingslashit( dirname(WSS_EXTESION) ));

require_once WSS_EXTESION_DIR . '/WebSecurity.php';
```

WebSecurity.php

```
<?php

require_once WSS_EXTESION_DIR . '/includes/Form.php'; 

class WebSecurity
{

    function __construct()
    {
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'ws_add_menu'));
    }

    function ws_add_menu()
    {

        add_menu_page(
            'Web Application Scanner', 
            'Web App Scanner', 
            'manage_options', 
            'Web_App_Scanner_menu',
            array(__CLASS__,'ws_page_render')
            );

    }

    function ws_page_render()
    {
        new Form();
    }

}

new WebSecurity();

?>
```

Form.php

```
<?php

class Form
{

    function __construct()
    {   
        //browser finds the style sheet
        echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'resources/css/ws-style.css';

        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'ws_load_css_1') );

        include_once WSS_EXTESION_DIR . '/includes/views/request_form.php';
    }

    function ws_load_css_1() 
    {
          wp_register_style( 'ws_css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'resources/css/ws-style.css');
          wp_enqueue_style( 'ws_css' );
    }    
}
```

request_form.php

```
<html>
    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <form action="request_form.php" method="post">

                <label>Naam</label>
                <input type="text" name="naam">

                <label>Bedrijf</label>
                <input type="text" name="bedrijf">

                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email">

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="verstuur">

            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.wrapper{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How about adding `new Form();` somewhere?  Also, when working in WP, you should be careful about function and class names.  `Form` is very, very generic.  I'd recommend something like `MelkaForm` or similar, to make it a bit more unique.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, It works, calling the method in ws_page_render() { ..., array(__CLASS__,'ws_page_render'); } doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Use `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts` to enqueue assets in admin panel. Edit `Form` class constructor like below :

```
function __construct()
{   
     add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts',array($this, 'ws_load_css'));
     include_once WSS_EXTESION_DIR . '/includes/views/request_form.php';
}
```

`wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook used for enqueuing on front pages.

`admin_enqueue_scripts` action hook used for enqueuing on admin pages.

**Update**

Also you must use css file url instead of path. Edit your `ws_load_css()` function and use `plugin_dir_url()` function like below :

```
function ws_load_css()
{
  wp_enqueue_style('style',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'resources/css/ws-style.css');
}
```

For new version of your code edit your `load_custom_wp_admin_style()` function like below :

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
        wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'resources/css/ws-style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
    }
```

**Note** : use `resources/css/ws-style.css` instead of `/resources/css/ws-style.css`.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I have aplied your solution but it didn't work.

Comment: Check your browser console for 404 error. Your `resource` directory is singular but you used plural `resources` in your `ws_load_css()` function.

Comment: Also check your page source head tag for style.css.

Comment: That was a mistake in the project structure, sorry.

Comment: Is the function ws_load_css correct, I'm using wp instead of admin?

Comment: You must use `admin_enqueue_scripts` for admin pages and `wp_enqueue_scripts` for front pages.

Comment: Still didn't work, I have updated the Form class. Maybe it's the path to the css file.

Comment: Check your browser console and your page source.

Comment: Sorry about that. the browser can find the css file, so that is some progress.

Comment: I think you have problem in your css file url. check browser console for 404 error.

Comment: So, "didn't work" doesn't help.  Use clearer language, and apply some troubleshooting. The problem is that nowhere in your code do you have `new Form()`, therefore the class is never getting called, and never constructed / enqueuing anything.

Comment: Check page source in browser. Do you see `<link>` tag with `http://cms.local/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/web_security_extension/includes/resources/css/ws-style.css` in its href attribute.